# Sender: AnyObject crashes when UIBarButtonItem is pressed

Tags: ios, swift, sender

I am having trouble understanding how to create a `BarButtonItem` and set the sender to AnyObject. I created a `BarButtonItem` programmatically and tried to set the sender as any object but the app crashes when the button is pressed.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    var toggle = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Settings", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "toggleSideMenu")
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = toggle

  }

func toggleSideMenu(sender: AnyObject) {
    toggleSideMenuView()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That "selector" has a parameter, so it should be:

```
action: "toggleSideMenu:"
                       ^
```

Plus the method itself will need an `@objc` annotation and I'm pretty sure that `sender` is optional, so:

```
@objc func toggleSideMenu(sender: AnyObject?) {
    toggleSideMenuView()
}
```

Comment: El Paseo de Colon, eh? ;-)